# First row in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns, which looks like:

```
Col1    col2    col3
101426  101426  40
101426  101426  49
101426  101426  80
101441  101441  30
101441  101441  40
101441  101441  49
101441  101441  80
101582  101582  49
101582  101582  80
101612  101612  80
101693  101693  31
101693  101693  40
101693  101693  80
101796  101796  80
101865  101865  30
101865  101865  40
```

want to get following records, which are the first record in a group of `col1` and `col2`

```
101426  101426  40
101441  101441  30
101582  101582  49
101612  101612  80
101693  101693  31
101796  101796  80
101865  101865  30
```

Comment: First ordered by what column(s)? Apart from that, what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Select * from (
select *,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by col1 order by col1 asc ) as a
 from A
 )myTable
where a = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
  SELECT Col1,Col2, MIN(col3)
    FROM myTable
GROUP BY Col1,Col2
```

Comment: This is not the goal.